# Custom Pytorch Lightning metric for loss function is causing errors during metric.forward & update calls

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-forecasting, torchmetrics

- PyTorch-Forecasting version: 1.0.0
- PyTorch version: 2.1.0
- Python version: 3.10.13
- Torchmetrics version: 1.2.0
- Operating System: Windows 10

#### Expected behavior

I defined a custom class for a loss function and attempted to train a TFT. I placed a breakpoint in the loss function. The expectation was for the model to train using the custom loss function. When I run the model without specifying a loss, it runs fine.

My dataset is from a dataframe of 8 columns: 3 are positions (float), 3 are parameters (float), 'i' for group number (int), and 'time' for a time index that resets for each group. I defined the training set as 75% of max time and the validation set as the full dataset.

No issues when the `loss=plPINNLoss` is commented out, but when it's given errors are being thrown. This can only mean there's either an issue in my implementation or MultiHorizonMetric.

#### Problematic Behavior

I've been getting errors such as: `'Tensor' object has no attribute '_is_synced'` from torchmetrics.metrics.py's `forward(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any)` function call where it checks `if self._is_synced`. A tensor is passed instead. This is coming from `pytorch_forecasting.metrics.base_metrics.TorchMetricWrapper -> forward()` which has `return self.torchmetric.forward(y_pred_flattened, target_flattened, **kwargs)`.

A breakpoint in `base_metrics.py` lets me see that `self.torchmetric` is my plPinnLoss which inherits MultiHorizonMetric. When I modify the foward call in debug console to `self.torchmetric.forward(self, y_pred_flattened, target_flattened, **kwargs)`, the error returned is then `TypeError: Metric.reset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.`  Again in debug console I try `self.torchmetric.reset(self)` which works. I make the modification to the source code in MultiHorizonMetrics, which leads to another error in MultiHorizonMetric.update on line 782:

`lengths = torch.full((target.size(0),), fill_value=target.size(1), dtype=torch.long, device=target.device)` where the error is `IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)`. The tensor passed in as target to update is 1 dimensional of size 128 (the batch size), so target.size(1) is invalid.

Something is clearly wrong, but I don't know enough about how to correct this. Is it in the construction of the metric used as a loss function?

#### Code

```
from pytorch_forecasting.metrics import MultiHorizonMetric
from pytorch_forecasting import TimeSeriesDataSet

train_AllTargets = TimeSeriesDataSet(data = train_df[lambda x: x.time <= int(0.75*t_max)],
                                     time_idx = "time",
                                     target = ['x','y','z','a','b','c'],
                                     group_ids = ['i'],
                                     static_reals = ['a','b','c'],
                                     time_varying_known_reals = ['time'],
                                     time_varying_unknown_reals = ['x','y','z']}
                                     )

train_loader = train_AllTargets.to_dataloader(train = True, batch_size=128)
val_loader = val_AllTargets.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size = 128)

class plPINNLoss(MultiHorizonMetric):
    higher_is_better = False
    full_state_update = False
    def __init__(self):
        super(plPINNLoss, self).__init__()
        self.add_state("total", default= torch.tensor(0), dist_reduce_fx="mean")
    def phys_loss(self, y_pred: Dict[str, torch.Tensor], target: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        # Simple toy case
        x, y, z = y_pred[:, 0], y_pred[:, 1], y_pred[:, 2]
        a, b, c = y_pred[:, 3], y_pred[:, 4], y_pred[:, 5]
        loss = torch.mean(x**2+y**2+z**2+a**2+b**2+c**2)
        total += loss
        
    def loss(self, y_pred: Dict[str, torch.Tensor], target: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.total

tftmodel = TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    dataset= train_AllTargets
    loss = plPINNLoss
    )

trainer = pl.Trainer(
    max_epochs=300,
    accelerator="auto",
    gradient_clip_val=0.1,
    callbacks = lr_logger,
    logger = logger,
    check_val_every_n_epoch=1
)
res = Tuner(trainer).lr_find(tftmodel, train_dataloaders=train_loader, val_dataloaders=val_loader)
```